# How to avoid multiple constant drivers in verilog

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I have some variables in an `initial` block

```
  initial
  begin
    i = 32'b0;
    j = 32'b1;
  end
```

I want to initialize them with initial values like this every time I press a pushbutton

```
always @(posedge btn)
begin
        i = 32'b0;
        j = 32'b1;
end
```

Doing it like this gives the error "can't resolve multiple constant driver" and I know why it happens but, is there another way around??

Comment: which tool gives you the error? There should be no error here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are creating synthesizable code (based on your need to press a button).  Initial blocks do not synthesize to logic, they are only used for simulation.  Typically you use a reset signal to set initial values.

Also you generally want to keep the logic for any one signal in a single block, instead of separating it into separate blocks. (again, this is for synthesizeable code, for simulation this is not important)

Finally, You generally do not want to use outside async signals to clock some logic (unless you know what you are doing).  You would instead code something like:

```
//---- detect rising edge of btn ----
reg btn_prev;
wire rising_edge_btn;
always @(posedge clk)
    btn_prev <= btn;

assign rising_edge_btn = ~btn_prev & btn;

// ---- i and j logic  --------------  
always @(posedge clk) begin
        if( rst || rising_edge_btn) begin
            i <= 0;
            j <= 1;
        end
        else 
            //some other logic here
        end
end
```

the code above uses a synchronous reset signal "rst".  You can also find designs with an asynchronous reset.  It would be good practice to also synchronize your outside async btn signal with with 2 flip flops to avoid metastability.